# Looking for the optimized MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I want to build a query which should be optimized performance wise when executed.
Below is my table structure:-

Table Name :- inventory

Table Structure :-

```
item_id int(50) Primary key,
item_name varchar(50),
matchingItemID int(50).
```

From the above table, I want to find the matching pairs of items,
i.e. If A and B are two items with item_id 1 and 2 respectively, then the value in the field named matchingItemID must be 2 and 1 respectively.

matchingItemID is the item_id of the item added.

For e.g.

```
item_id     item_name      matchingItemID
   1            A                2
   2            B                1
```

So, the query builded should return the output as follows:-

A - B.

I have tried one query, but it takes time in execution and hence I think its not optimized performance wise.

Below is the query that I have built:-

```
SELECT a.item_id, b.item_id
FROM inventory a, inventory b
WHERE a.matchingItemID = b.item_id
AND b.matchingItemID = a.item_id
AND a.item_id != b.item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If items always match mutually, you can do:

```
SELECT a.item_id, b.item_id
FROM inventory a
JOIN inventory b ON a.matchingItemID = b.item_id
```

Also, you can add an index to the `matchingItemID` column.

EDIT

Seems redundant, but this is what you asked for:

```
SELECT a.item_id, b.item_id
FROM inventory a
JOIN inventory b ON a.matchingItemID = b.item_id AND b.matchingItemID = a.item_id
```

Comment: It is necessary that b.matchingItemID should also match with the item_id of that of a.

Comment: If they are pairs, they will match - `A=B` means `B=A`

Comment: Just in case, I've added an update so it covers the other case as well.

Comment: that query, I have already have but its not optimized performance wise as it takes time for execution.

Comment: you didn't have that query (you had no `join`s) and if you're not satisfied with performance, you need to reorganize your data because this is as fast as you can get for what you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have two records with `A=B` and `B=A` then just use this query it outputs only distinct one pair `A=B` instead of two:

```
SELECT a.item_id id1, b.item_id id2
FROM inventory a
join inventory b on 
    (a.matchingItemID = b.item_id)
    AND 
    (b.matchingItemID = a.item_id)
    AND 
    (a.item_id < b.item_id)
```

Comment: I tried this query, but its not working. It fetches no records although I have such records in my database.

Comment: It have to work fine. Here is a [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96d8a/2) for your data.